# Difference between START n = node(*) and MATCH (n)

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4j 2.0 this query:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.username = 'blevine' 
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[:Person]->person
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[:UserLink]->role
RETURN n AS user,person,collect(role) AS roles
```

returns different results than this query:

```
START n = node(*) WHERE n.username = 'blevine' 
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[:Person]->person
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[:UserLink]->role
RETURN n AS user,person,collect(role) AS roles
```

The first query works as expected returning a single Node for 'blevine' and the associated Nodes mentioned in the OPTIONAL MATCH clauses.  The second query returns many more Nodes  which do not even have a username property.  I realize that start n = node(*) is not recommended and that START is not even required in 2.0.  But the second form (with OPTIONAL MATCH replaced with question marks on the relationship type) worked prior to 2.0.  In the second form, why is 'n' not being constrained to the single 'blevine' node by the first WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the second query as expected you would just need to add `WITH n`. In your query you would need to filter the result and pass it for optional match which is to be done using WITH

```
START n = node(*) WHERE n.username = 'blevine' 
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[:Person]->person
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[:UserLink]->role
RETURN n AS user,person,collect(role) AS roles
```

From the documentation

```
WHERE defines the MATCH patterns in more detail. The predicates are part of the 
pattern description, not a filter applied after the matching is done. 
This means that WHERE should always be put together with the MATCH clause it belongs to.
```

when you do start n=node(*) where n.name="xyz" you need to pass the result explicitly into your next optional matches. But when you do MATCH (n) WHERE n.name="xyz" this tells graph specifically what node to start looking into.

**EDIT**

Here is the thing. The documentation says Optional Match returns `null` if a pattern is not found so in your first case, it includes all those results too where `n.username` property is `null` or cases where `n` doesnt even have a relationship suggested in the `OPTIONAL MATCH` pattern. So when you do a `WITH n` , the graph is explicitly told to use only n.

Excerpt from the documentation (link : [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-optional-match.html))

```
OPTIONAL MATCH matches patterns against your graph database, just like MATCH does. 
The difference is that if no matches are found, OPTIONAL MATCH will use NULLs for 
missing parts of the pattern. OPTIONAL MATCH could be considered the Cypher 
equivalent of the outer join in SQL.


Either the whole pattern is matched, or nothing is matched. Remember that 
WHERE is part of the pattern description, and the predicates will be 
considered while looking for matches, not after. This matters especially
in the case of multiple (OPTIONAL) MATCH clauses, where it is crucial to 
put WHERE together with the MATCH it belongs to.
```

Also few more things to note about the behaviour of WHERE clause: [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html)

Excerpts:

```
WHERE is not a clause in it’s own right — rather, it’s part of MATCH, 
OPTIONAL MATCH, START and WITH.

In the case of WITH and START, WHERE simply filters the results.

For MATCH and OPTIONAL MATCH on the other hand, WHERE adds constraints
to the patterns described. It should not be seen as a filter after the
matching is finished.
```

Comment: So is this an explicit difference in how WHERE clauses behave in Neo4j 1.x and 2.x?  I've read the section on where clauses you posted and was wondering whether it was meant as a clarification on how WHERE clauses work (even in 1.x) which if so, I guess I never completely understood.  Or whether it was meant to indicate new WHERE clause behavior in 2.x

Comment: See where clause is to be used with match clause . Their combination tells graph about the pattern it needs to look in the graph to start querying. While when you do start node(*) With where clause the graph probably goes to all nodes and checks those with attribute ..

Comment: I can understand that the entire graph is traversed any time you use start n = node( * ). But, when following that with a WHERE clause, I would have expected the starting node to be constrained by that WHERE clause (thereby constraining the traversal of the graph by the MATCH clauses) which it appears to be when I pass the result to subsequent OPTIONAL MATCH clauses with a WITH clause.  Prior to Neo4j2.0, the query: START n = node( * ) WHERE n.username = 'blevine' MATCH n-[?:Person]->person, n-[?:UserLink]->role RETURN ... worked as expected

Comment: It would still work the same if you replace the optional  matches with MATCH  without any WITH Clause.

Comment: My intent was to constrain the results by specifying a starting point using the START plus WHERE clause.  Are you saying that the OPTIONAL clause causes that starting point to be ignored?  If so, then I guess that a clause like MATCH n-[?:Person]->person in 1.x is not equivalent to OPTIONAL MATCH n-[:Person]->person in 2.x

Comment: Thank you Sumeet, that clears things up a bit and I think I understand the effect that the OPTIONAL MATCH statements are having on the query (the outer join behavior).  The statement in the documentation that for WITH and START the WHERE clause simply filters results is confusing. Since the first WHERE clause filtered the results of the START clause to a single node, I figured that only that node single would be considered as the starting point when the MATCH statements were evaluated.  I guess that's not how it works though.  Thanks again.